# Как на JS определить, простое или составное число?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, простые-числа, перебор

> Дано число n (n > 0). Проверьте, простое оно или составное. Если число простое - верните из функции строку "Простое число", если нет - "Составное число". Воспользуйтесь методом перебора делителей числа.

Пыталась сделать так, не работает (знаю, что длинно и неудобно):

```
function testCycle(n) {
    var x = "";
    if (n < 2) {
        x = "Число должно быть больше 1";
    } else if (n === 2) {
        x = "Простое число";
    }
    i = 2;
    limit = Math.sqrt(n);
    while (i <= limit) {
        i += 1;
        if (n % i == 0) {
            x = "Составное число";
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: вы правильно код вставили? у вас, кажется, `return` снаружи функции

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправила

Comment: почему у вас в коде нигде не возвращается "Составное число"? Если `n % i === 0`, это как раз составное число

Comment: и `return` вы не туда перенесли)

Comment: Ох... )) да, сейчас всё исправлю, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Ну и возможные делители перебирать можно не с 2, а с 3, и сразу через один, а не подряд. Да ещё пропускать те, что не 5, но делятся на 5... а на 2 попробовать делить до перебора.

Comment: Не работает всё равно, к сожалению.

Comment: `return` так и не перенесли в нужное место)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// === More readable ===
/**
* Preliminary checks:
*
* Checks whether the number n is less than or 
* equal to 1. If so, the function returns an 
* error.
* It checks whether n is equal to 2 or 3. If it 
* is, the number is considered prime.
* Checking for divisibility by 2 and 3:
*
* It checks whether the number n is divisible by 
* 2 or 3. If it is divisible, the number is said 
* to be composite.
* Checking for divisibility by 6k ± 1:
*
* An optimised approach is used to check 
* division by numbers of the form 6k ± 1 (except 
* 2 and 3), which reduces the number of 
* divisions.
*/


function speedTest(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 'error';
    }

    if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
        return 'Prime';
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return 'Composite';
    }

    //the divisors of a number cannot be greater than its square root.
    const sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);

    for (let i = 5; i <= sqrt; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 'Composite';
        }
    }

    for (let i = 7; i <= sqrt; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 'Composite';
        }
    }

    return 'Prime';
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: По какой-то чудесной причине, действительно работает... знать бы, как это строго доказать) `i*i <= n` — Выполняет умножение на каждой итерации. Можно заранее сохранить `Math.sqrt(n)` и проверять `i <= sqrt`

Answer (score 3):

```js
function isPrime(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return 'Число должно быть больше 1';
  } else if (n === 2) {
    return 'Простое число';
  }

  let i = 2;
  const limit = Math.sqrt(n);
  while (i <= limit) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      return 'Составное число';
    }
    i +=1;
  }
  
  return 'Простое число';
}


console.log(100, isPrime(100));
console.log(7, isPrime(7));
console.log(0, isPrime(0));
console.log(23, isPrime(23));
console.log(2, isPrime(2));
```

**Из комментариев**
@Akina

> Ну и возможные делители перебирать можно не с 2, а с 3, и сразу через один, а не подряд. Да ещё пропускать те, что не 5, но делятся на 5... а на 2 попробовать делить до перебора

Это уже сами попробуйте реализовать ;)

Comment: Вот это да! Спасибо. Ваш способ тоже попробую сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Простое число имеет всего два делителя, 1 и само себя, все остальные составные. В начале ставим условие, что число должно быть больше 1, и дальше с помощью цикла прогоняем все делители этого числа. Если хотя бы одно число делит num без остатка - число составное.

```
function primeNumb(num) {
  if (num > 1) {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        return "Составное число";
      }
    }
    return "Простое число";
  } else {
    return "Число должно быть больше 1";
  }
}

console.log(primeNumb(2));
```